# CPU Stuck at 100% on Customer PC, any debugging suggestions?

Tags: .net, debugging, ms-access-2007, cpu, jet

I'm having a dead-end situation with one of the clients using my software. Out of about 40 copies of our product sold (Application programmed in .NET 2.0 using VB.NET 2005), about 2 get non-responsive with 1 core of the dual core CPUs stuck at 100% (program uses 1 core only)

The most logical guess is an infinite loop causing this behavior, but the are thousands of lines of code with many, many loops. That is all the information I've got; now, how do you suggest I approach debugging this problem?

EDIT:
Basically, the software is responsible for calculating amount of credit spent using other devices, such as PCs, etc. It is a Cybercafe management program and fails intermittently i.e. it is subtracting credit when is fails. It does other things in the background too, like checking to see if it is time to create a database backup, among other things.

EDIT:
Solved. It was the most unlikely problem. The Access Database Engine which I used as the DBMS is actually the part of my application that is problematic. It has difficulty working with a row-JUST ONE FRIGGIN ROW-in one of the tables. I can't delete it, or otherwise add a record related to that row in any other table; Even MS Access 2007 causes the CPU to go up to 100% when I try to work with that row!

A simple "Compact and Repair" command fixed everything. I guess I'll issue that command every time my application starts up. That would prevent this from happening again.

Thanks to WinDbg I could find where the problem was. I recommend everyone to learn how to use it 'cause it's a real time saver.

Comment: You are selling a product using a Jet/ACE back end and you didn't know about the importance of routine maintenance of your data store? Your clients should sue you for incompetence.

Comment: I didn't think the people at Microsoft would be so inconsiderate to say "Hey, your database WILL get corrupt, you have to use a menu command in Access to fix it!"
Would they say the same thing to people using SQL Server?!

Comment: It's Jet, they don't have to say that.  ;)  One of the chief, unspoken selling points of SQL Server is, "It's not Jet."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install windbg (Windows debugger) on the target machine. Invoke the debugger, and attach to the suspicious process, run the program and then wait until problem happens. When the problem happens, invoke the following command in the debugger command line

!runaway

This will show which of your threads are consuming most of the time. Then get several thread stacks from that thread that is consuming most of your cpu resources.

Here is an example:

```
0:015> !runaway
```

User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
   0:1074      0 days 0:00:21.637
  11:137c      0 days 0:00:02.792
   4:12c8      0 days 0:00:00.530
   9:1374      0 days 0:00:00.046
  15:13d0      0 days 0:00:00.000
  14:1204      0 days 0:00:00.000
  13:154c      0 days 0:00:00.000
  12:144c      0 days 0:00:00.000
  10:1378      0 days 0:00:00.000
   8:1340      0 days 0:00:00.000
   7:12f0      0 days 0:00:00.000
   6:12d4      0 days 0:00:00.000
   5:12d0      0 days 0:00:00.000
   3:12c4      0 days 0:00:00.000
   2:12c0      0 days 0:00:00.000
   1:12b4      0 days 0:00:00.000

Now assume we want a call stack for the second thread in the list, thread 11, so we first switch to thread 11. This can be done by entering ~11s.

```
0:015> ~11s
```

eax=03fbb270 ebx=ffffffff ecx=00000002 edx=00000060 esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=77475e74 esp=0572f60c ebp=0572f67c iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
77475e74 c3              ret

Now get a call stack for this thread by executing kp:

```
0:011> kp
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0572f608 77475620 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0572f60c 75b09884 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
0572f67c 75b097f2 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xbe
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3.1 Beta 1\nspr4.dll - 
0572f690 10019a0b kernel32!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0572f6ac 10015979 nspr4!PR_MD_WAIT_CV+0x8b
0572f6c4 10015763 nspr4!PR_GetPrimordialCPU+0x79
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox 3.1 Beta 1\xul.dll - 
0572f6e0 64d44d6a nspr4!PR_Wait+0x33
0572f708 64dbe67e xul!NS_CycleCollectorForget2_P+0x698a
0572f72c 10019b3f xul!gfxWindowsPlatform::FontEnumProc+0xfd4e
0572f734 10015d32 nspr4!PR_MD_UNLOCK+0x1f
0572f738 1001624b nspr4!PR_Unlock+0x22
0572f754 1001838d nspr4!PRP_TryLock+0x4cb
00000000 00000000 nspr4!PR_Now+0x109d
```

The command kp will print the parameters. Local variables can be printed with dv.

Alternatively you can use process explorer from sysinternals.

If all this is not possible, because it is a remote client machine, install userdump, which creates a dump file that can be sent to you for further analysis. You can create a batch file for the customer to invoke userdump with the correct parameters. Userdump is a tool from Microsoft, which can be downloaded from their web page.

Comment: I see numbers as identifiers for threads. How can I know which thread it is that is causing problems? Is there a way to know which method that particular thread is executing?

Comment: This was quite helpful. Now the only thing I need is to know what parameters have been sent to all the methods in the stack. How do I get the parameter values?

Answer (score 4):

If possible, get a process dump and look at the stack trace.
I never did it but it should work with VS/WinDbg and SOS (Son of Strike).
Here is a [blog post](http://www.dumpanalysis.org/blog/index.php/2007/07/20/crash-dump-analysis-patterns-part-17/) about it.

Answer (score 4):

If it is an infinite loop, then try attaching a debugger and hitting break.  WinDbg is ideal for this.

The technique also works for the case when the loop is just iterating too many times but eventually carries on with the rest of the code.  It is possible to spend a couple of minutes repeating the procedure to get a good sample.

This technique has saved me several times and works well for hung applications too :)

Comment: +1  Excellent suggestion, Thomas.  It seems like a lot of developers today do not use applications like WinDbg.  SOS will be required for providing information about the CLR, as well.  Link provided for the OP's reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx

Comment: Thanks :)  Good point about SOS.  The magic line for .NET is: '.loadby sos mscorwks'

Comment: WinDbg is not a managed code system.  Most dev's who've never even seen C++ code have no idea it exists.  I do but I don't use it every day which makes it harder again when I do have to use it.  You have to write some really interesting code to need windbg in C#.

Comment: Not that interesting though ;)  I find it excellent for tracking .NET memory leaks (using gcroot etc) which just can't be done in the same way with MS Visual Studio.

Comment: Such tools have to become a part of VS, with some improved UI. I have to google the crap out of the net to understand it can't debug .NET applications on its own.

Answer (score 2):

Well you'll need to work out where it's tight-looping. What is your client doing with the software at the time? What does the software do in the first place?

You might want to consider adding a lot of logging to your code and giving the client a copy with all that logging enabled, helping you to trace where they're having problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use a logger like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html) which you can introduce to your existing codebase with [postsharp](http://www.postsharp.org/). Log all method entries and exits - so you should find the faulty method. Then you can improve your logging if it is still required.

It looks like this is working for vb.net, too, although I have no experience there. Maybe [this article](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DesktopDev/MSTech/vb-net-using-postsharp-and-log4postsharp) helps you a bit.

Comment: Aha. Tracing everything with Postsharp could truly do the trick and narrow findings to particular function.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to interview those clients very thoroughly. That's not always easy but it is your only shot at narrowing the problem down.

Then carefully add Tracing, and don't forget to Flush at strategic points (or set AutoFlush).

But it could be a subtle timing problem that goes away due to the added delay of tracing...

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with single-core and multi-core CPUs behaving differently, for example when a background thread tries to update the UI.

(And I admit that I wrote an app back in the dark ages that did not cleanly separate background and UI threads and caused problems when multi-core CPUs got mainstream. The solution was to call the SetProcessAffinity to restrict the app to a single core)

If that's the case, you should check whether the 100% CPU only occur with a special kind of CPU, and whether using SetProcessAffinity solves the problem. If it does, you know where to look for in your code.

Comment: You can set CPU affinity on a running process using the free Process Explorer utility.  It should be enough to see whether devio's answer helps.

Comment: I know, Windows TaskMgr can do it too.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be a threading problem? "fails intermittently" makes 
me think of it. Does the program receive signals/messages 
from the outside, like remoting/DCOM/sockets? Is progress 
information related to such messages presented in the user 
interface?

I once detected a threading problem because I always use a 
lot of ASSERTs. There was a sanity check ASSERT for the beginning 
of a message received through XML-RPC to be:

```
"<?xml "
```

and the ASSERT catched an overwrite of the memory of the message. By 
inspection this turned out to be due a missing lock in a 
critical section. This detection was only possible because 
the problem was catched so early by the ASSERT (and it 
happened sufficiently often to be detected).

This is not very specfific or directed advice, but my 
suggestion then is to add ASSERTs in places that may be 
affected a threading problem.

Note that firing ASSERTs does not necessarily imply aborting 
the program or throw message boxes. ASSERTs can be 
redirected to a log file instead, including the full stack 
trace at the time of the ASSERT firing.